# Does Google allow GCP Kubernetes application deployment to Google Bare Metal directly?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google, google-kubernetes-engine, bare-metal

From the google marketplace - https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace can I deploy an application directly to Google Bare Metal ? - https://cloud.google.com/bare-metal.

Especially the applications supported by Anthos like - https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/neo4j-public/causal-cluster-k8s

Comment: Did you try @MrKoopaKiller solution?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that using GKE On-premises.

> GKE on-prem is hybrid cloud software that brings Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) to on-premises data centers. GKE on-prem is a reliable, efficient, and secured way to run Kubernetes clusters anywhere.

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=308&v=U61TKOhixiQ&feature=emb_logo) you can find a video showing a deploy of InfluxDB into GKE On-premises

And here you can find more information about the product:

https://cloud.google.com/anthos/gke/docs/on-prem/